# How do I cancel Erron Black's 21122 into his command throw?

Tags: mortal-kombat-x

How do I cancel Erron Black's Put Em Up into his command throw? Everytime I do the 21122 and attempt the command throw in the end it's either a missed tarkatan stab or an uppercut.